# How to capture the total value of the sale and the order number in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Sorry, I'm using online translator.

I use the following script on the page (app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/onepage/Success.php) in magento that is working normally capturing the sample values (27.99) and (My Product Description). How do I get it to capture the full value of the sale and the order number?

```
<?php
$sale_amount = '27.99';
$product = 'My Product Description';
include('afiliados/controller/record-sale.php');
?>
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
echo $order->getGrandTotal();
```

Comment: Let me know if you need any other values

Comment: I changed to $product = $orderId; and now this capturing the order number, but when I add $sale_amount = '$order->getGrandTotal();'; It is not capturing the value, this recording as 0.00 and when manually add for example $sale_amount = '10.00'; it writes the value reported 10.00

Can you help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you show your full code? You need to make sure you are loading the order before getting the total.

Comment: I got the following:

$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$sale_amount = $order->getGrandTotal();

Thank you very much.